# Which external Audio Processing technology can Flash Player interact with in realtime?

Tags: flash, external, signal-processing, audio

There may be more than one answer to this, but I'd like to know if there's some technology out there that exists to handle Audio Processing / Playback in realtime, so that Flash can:

- Interface with the technology / plugin to generate sounds with no delay or lag.
- Apply DSP effects (Reverb, Delay, Dynamic Range Compression / Expansion, Distortion, etc).
- Manipulate DSP parameters in realtime (sweeping an EQ filter's band or Q).

The most important thing of all, would be for this technology to be available to most users, as it would likely be used for Gaming environments or online Audio production, even.

So far, Flash has a few ways to manipulate Audio Data, such as the [SampleDataEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html), Andre Michelle's [Popforge](http://code.google.com/p/popforge/) library, chiptune libraries like [SiON](https://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/), and possibly some other unheard of libraries.

I'm not really convinced though, that these methods are the optimal ways to create interactive sounds - sounds that change depending on game conditions, sounds that closely responds to the users actions. Nothing (that I've seen so far) easily allows developers to create or communicate with a DSP effect in order to manipulate the sound in this way, in realtime.

I know that Flash has the ability to communicate over sockets / ports, so perhaps there is an existing library that can communicate with an external plugin, and can be easily distributed to users at the same time.

Is there such an audio solution out there?

Answer (score 0):

I know this : http://www.audiotool.com/app but don't know how they do, there is a blog explain some code (first name was hobnox), try a search.

I have seen some app in flash using java lib to access to audio fx, another idea is to try MIDI communication (It's better for real time).

Comment: Thanks @benoît. I've seen AudioTool (even back in the days when, as you said, it was called Hobnox). I don't think their Sound API is available for the Flash Dev community however.
As for Java, making an Applet that communicates with Flash might be a good approach. I wouldn't invest too much time with MIDI however, as it wouldn't really be fair to require each user to have some MIDI sequencing / instrument plugin installed.